# Can jq produce output without newlines between fields, one line per record?

Tags: json, jq, jsonlines

jq always produces output with newlines/returns between each field:

```
jq ... foo.json
{
  "Name": "stedolan",
  "RecordTimestamp": "2021-02-25T05:00:06.740+0000"
}
```

How can I make the output one line per record so that it looks like:

```
{"Name":"stedolan","RecordTimestamp":"2021-02-25T05:00:06.740+0000"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jq has an option for this:  --compact-output

```
jq --compact-output ... foo.json
{"Name":"stedolan","RecordTimestamp":"2021-02-25T05:00:06.740+0000"}
```

Full manual https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/